# How can we do a Gaussian integral over matrix elements?

Tags: integration, random-matrices, gaussian

I am integrating the following Gaussian over all possible matrix elements $J_{ij}$:
$$ I=\int \exp{\left\{-a\sum_{ij}J_{ij}^2+b\sum_{ij}J_{ij}+c\sum_{ij}J_{ij}J_{ji} \right\}} \left (\prod_{ij}\mathrm{d}J_{ij} \right)$$

How can I deal with the $\sum_{ij}J_{ij}J_{ji}$ terms? The fact that I am integrating over matrix elements confuses me. Any help or advice is always appreciated, thanks !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Decompose the sum over $i,j$ as
$$-a\sum_{ij}J_{ij}^2+b\sum_{ij}J_{ij}+c\sum_{ij}J_{ij}J_{ji}=$$
$$\qquad\qquad=\sum_{i}\left[(c-a)J_{ii}^2+bJ_{ii}\right]+\sum_{i<j}\left[-a(J_{ij}^2+J_{ji}^2)+b(J_{ij}+J_{ji})+2cJ_{ij}J_{ji}\right]$$
$$\qquad\qquad\equiv\sum_{i} A_i+\sum_{i<j} B_{ij}.$$
Then perform the Gaussian integrals separately for each term in the sum (assuming $c<a$ and $c^2/a<a$),
$$I=\left(\prod_{i=1}^N\int e^{A_i}dJ_{ii}\right)\left(\prod_{i<j=1}^{N}\int\int e^{B_{ij}}dJ_{ij}dJ_{ji}\right)$$
$$\qquad\qquad=\left(\frac{\sqrt{\pi } e^{\frac{b^2}{4 a-4 c}}}{\sqrt{a-c}}\right)^N\left(\frac{\pi  e^{\frac{b^2}{2 a-2 c}}}{\sqrt{a^2-c^2}}\right)^{N(N-1)/2}=\pi^{N^2/2}e^{\frac{N^2b^2}{4a-4c}}(a-c)^{-N/2}(a^2-c^2)^{-N(N-1)/2}.$$

Comment: Thank you, it makes a lot sense now. If $b\equiv b_{ij}$ depends on $i$ and $j$, does the second integral become : $\propto e^{\frac{a(b_{ij}^2+b_{ji}^2)+2c(b_{ij}b_{ji})}{4(a^2-c^2)}}$ ?

Comment: yes, that is correct.